# Eclipse Force.com IDE save/Deployment

Tags: apex, eclipse, force.com-ide

When we deploy a class file using eclipse Force.com IDE, save command, does it make a deploy call? It is bizarre that it shows deployment logs for few req save commands and not others. I used ctrl+s to save a file and not 'save to server'. Yet its show deployment logs few times.

Comment: I can't speak to the internals of the force.com ide itself, but in salesforce sandbox environments, there are alternative ways of manipulating apex classes that don't involve a metadata api deploy() call.

Comment: @martin, I am using the developer environment.

Answer (score 2):

In the Force.com IDE there is a difference between saving the file locally and saving it to the SF server.

Saving it locally just saves the changes to your file system and doesn't compile it in Salesforce.

Saving it to the server uses a metadata api deploy call to compile the class in Salesforce.

The IDE doesn't save to the server by default - you have to explicitly tell it to save to server or adjust your settings to automatically save to server when you save the file locally. If you haven't set it to automatically save to the server then it's likely that you're seeing deploys only from times when the file was explicitly saved to the server.

Comment: I know what you are referring to. I am working on my project in online mode. which means when I save the file locally, it does updates the server files. What I am confused with is when I save the file locally, I donot see the deployment logs  consistently everytime. So trying to understand when does it save vs. deploy code to salesforce when I save the file locally(CTRL+S).